# Прямая речь. Какой из вариантов - правильный?

Tags: орфография

1.«В гостиницу для нищих», – ответил без раздумий и уточнил:
«В самую дешевую».
2.«В гостиницу для нищих, – ответил без раздумий и уточнил:
в самую дешевую».

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ни тот, ни другой. Если в авторских словах внутри прямой речи имеются 2 глагола со значением высказывания, из которых один относится к 1-й части, а другой - ко второй, то после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире. Это две реплики. Вторая начинается с большой буквы.

«В гостиницу для нищих, – ответил без раздумий и уточнил: - В самую дешевую».

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: «В гостиницу для нищих, – ответил без раздумий и уточнил:  - В самую дешевую».

Если слова автора распадаются по смыслу на две части, которые относятся к разным частям прямой речи, то при соблюдении других условий после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире: «Эхма... — безнадежно вздохнул Гаврила в ответ на суровое приказание и горько добавил: — Судьбина моя пропащая!» (М. Г.);

См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.